# How to lock/unlock phone from Service in android?

Tags: android, service

I want to lock/unlock android using a service. I have checked other questions but none works. Some require to have my app in foreground and some I don't understand well enough. I want to show the lock screen if the device is password locked else home screen.
Just Turning screen on and off only will also work. Anyone know how to do it?

Edit 1:
I have tried things and managed to turn on(WakeLock) and off(DevicePolicyManager) screen. However, turning off screen does not lock phone only turns off the display. I use `locknow()`. This is acceptable but if possible can anyone tell how to lock phone?

Edit 2:
I can not lock my phone even by using physical lock button. It just turns off the screen.

Comment: `I have checked other questions` which ones? So at least we don't suggest same solution. `some I don't understand well enough` then ask the guys who answered through comments.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Check my edit